# .txt file searching and output

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to look into a text file consisting of number that look like this.

> 89062 42765 80311 11046 21082 39746 49788 57004 885// 333 88650=

and return the 11th character (here an 8 but could be anything from a 0 to an 8), into a file with the name of the file and this number probably comma separated.

I need to look through a load of files and get this value out, but I should be able to work out how to look into the write ones I am just struggling with this bit.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're searching for? Do you need to find the text files with numbers like this? If so, where do these text files live and how do I know which one is the one I'm looking for? Do these text files contain more than one line? If so, how do I identify the line? Do you only need that one digit, or do you need the entire group?

Comment: Can you post what you tried so far to solve your problem?

Comment: As displayed below there was enough info here to get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The 11th character is a `5`

```
echo 89062 42765 80311 11046 21082 39746 49788 57004 885// 333 88650= | cut -c11
5
```

Unless you remove spaces:

```
echo 89062 42765 80311 11046 21082 39746 49788 57004 885// 333 88650= |tr -d " " | cut -c11
8
```

`cut -cn` extracts the n'th character

`tr` translates, but with `-d` deletes the named character, i.e. spaces

This will do all the files ending in `.txt`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.txt; do
   n=$(tr -d ' ' < "$f" | cut -c 11)
   echo $f:$n
done
```